# Can not compare PDO->query result to false

Tags: php, pdo

I make a PDO query with erroneous text. It suppose to return false.
And according to the debugger it does. The problem is that checking it for being false just doesn't work

```
$pdo = new PDO(...) // no errors here. correct requests work.
$result = $pdo->query("asdsadgsa");
if (!$result)
    echo "Never gets here";
```

Neither

```
if ($result == false)
```

Nor

```
if ($result === false)
```

It just never enters if body. Am I getting php comparison operators wrong?

Comment: difference between `==` and `===` is that `===` conpare and your type of variable , this mean `0 == false` but not `0 === false`

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was weird. Apparently rebooting + 30 min fb surfing solved this. Can not reproduce this again.